# String variable into CSS or JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, css, repeat

In this code below, how can I make `\"'.($img).'\"` repeat? By removing the image tag and using JavaScript or CSS?

```
<img src=\"'.($img).'\" alt=\"\" />
```

Here is the whole code:

```
function add_logo_css() {
    $img = get_option('add_logo_logo');
    if(!empty($img))
        echo '<style type="text/css">
                #admin-logo 
               { 
                     margin: 10px 0;
                     padding: 0 0 5px; 
                     border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;  
                     position:absolute; 
                     margin-left: 165px; 
                     width:100%; 
              }
               </style>'."\n";
}

function add_logo_script() {
    $img = get_option('add_logo_logo');
    if(!empty($img))
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                  /* <![CDATA[ */
                 (function($) {
                    $("#wpwrap").prepend("<div id=\"admin-logo\">
                    <img src=\"'.($img).'\" alt=\"\" /></div>");
                    })(jQuery);
                  /* ]]> */
                </script>';
}
```

Comment: why would you like to repeat `\"'.($img).'\"`? in your code , it seems that `\"'.($img).'\"` is a string path for the image. Am i right?

Comment: alternative way instead of putting those strings inside an echo and escaping them is to use the heredoc or just escape php

ie 

`<?php function add_logo_css() {
    $img = get_option('add_logo_logo');
    if(!empty($img))
?>
  <style type="text/css">
                #admin-logo 
               { 
                     margin: 10px 0;
                     padding: 0 0 5px; 
                     border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;  
                     position:absolute; 
                     margin-left: 165px; 
                     width:100%; 
              }
               </style>
<?php }?>`

Comment: yes it is the string path but how would you rewrite the code above for that path to repeat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the string of the src attribute for your image tag you can accomplish it via JS like so:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src
```

Of course you need to do this after page load, as you use a php variable to populate the image source, so:

```
function getSrc() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myImage").src
}
```

then call getSrc onload in the body tag or use window.load in javascript.

As far as whatever you mean by repeating it, you can do a number of different "repeat" things with JS.  For instance, to write the actual source string 10 times:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{    
    document.write(x);
}
```